# How to create a tile list that flows horizontally in wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hi i'm trying to get an effect similar to the way the marketplace displays apps. They have a horizontal list of six tiles that start in front and go off screen to the right. As you scroll the title for that view follows until you pass the final tiles then it goes to the next view of the panorama. This same effect is also used in the office hub with onenote. Any tips, suggestions or resources to help accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this approach by using the `Panorama` control and by setting the `Orientation` property to `Horizontal` for this item. There's a [How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941109%28VS.92%29.aspx) on MSDN that walks through this scenario.